# Can't access WSL files without starting manually starting WSL before

Tags: linux, networking, boot, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I'm trying to access Ubuntu WSL (2) files from Windows. Until recently, I was able to do so by accessing `\\wsl$\Ubuntu`, but now, I need to manually start Ubuntu WSL by launching the Ubuntu WSL app or by typing `wsl` in `PowerShell` or in `CMD`. `\\wsl$\Ubuntu` is not available after Windows has booted either. The hole thing lasts something like two minutes. After that, I have to manually launch WSL again. What do I need to do to be able to access WSL files without actually having starting WSL manually?

Comment: Are you manually shutting down the WSL instances? It’s always been required for the instances to be running

Answer (score 0):

I came here to see if someone had a better solution. That clearly hasn't happened lol. (just recently installed wsl).

What I do (really make shift solution but works) is go to file manager and type `\\wsl$` into the address bar. Then magically you will see your wsl files, it will even be in the side bar navigation. However you will have to do this for each new instance of file manager.

Hope this helps.